# Splitting Strings in java without removing the match

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string without removing the matched string, I was kind of successful as I found that this could be done using `(?<=-)|(?=-)`, but now if I implement it to extract a link,
using this regex expression: 
`((?<=(http:\\/\\/\\S+))|(?=(http:\\/\\/\\S+)))` I receive a weird outup.
In fact, splitting this input:

`A wonderful serenity has taken possession of http://www.google.com my entire soul,\n like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.`

gives me this set of strings:

`["A wonderful serenity has taken possession of ", "http://w", "w", "w", ".", "g", "o", "o", "g", "g", "l", "e", ".", "c", "o", "m", "my entire soul,\n like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart."]`.

EDIT:
The successful output should be:

`["A wonderful serenity has taken possession of ", "http://www.google.com", "my entire soul,\n like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart."]`

Comment: ...and what is the output you actually want to see here?

Comment: Sorry I now added the what kind of output I want

Comment: Too little, too late, but use this: `input.split("(?=https?://)")`

Comment: Let's get this reopened. I actually thought it was pretty clear, given the example regex for splitting on `-` without removing it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How will that split both *before* and *after* the "separator" token. The `(?<=-)|(?=-)` example given is obviously a regex for splitting before/after a `-`, which mean it is exactly what the question is asking about, i.e. how to do `split("-")` without removing the `-`, i.e. having the `-` be a returned value too.

Comment: @Andreas Oops...because of bad formatting, didn't see that the OP wanted to also split after the URL.  I have an answer, but I can't post it because the question has been closed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that doesn't work, as it returns the link chained to the other string

Comment: I reedited now it should be more understandable

Comment: A simple *search* for the "separator" and manual collection of the skipped text, will give you a fairly simple solution that doesn't do redundant matching operations, i.e. the logic is straightforward and will perform better. Since question is currently closed and we can't leave answers, see [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/s5QlPR) for solution.

Comment: @Andreas thanks at the end your solution helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One viable option here would be to use a formal regex iterator, and search for the following pattern:

```regex
\\bhttps?://\\S+\\b|.*?(?=https?://|$)
```

This pattern will first try to fish out a URL, if it can find, otherwise it will capture all content up, but including, either the next URL or the end of the input.  Here is a sample code:

```java
String input = "A wonderful serenity has taken possession of http://www.google.com my entire soul,\n like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.";
String pattern = "\\bhttps?://\\S+\\b|.*?(?=https?://|$)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

This prints:

```
[A wonderful serenity has taken possession of ,
 http://www.google.com,
 like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart., ]
```